# how to create comment box with php-mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Well I'm new in PHP.
I'm trying to create a comment box, but only logged in users can comment on it 
and that comment goes to my database along with logged in username.

I don't want comments to display it on web page
Provide some tutorial from where i can learn this thing
thank you in advance :)

Comment: before post your question,you must search with google for the tutorials.

Comment: use This is inside php.echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                           window.alert('hello');
                         </SCRIPT>");

Answer (score -1):

Follow that links it is very simple as you are new to php programming.

[Create simple comment box for logged in user using phpmysql](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-login-page-with-php-and-mysql/28656)

Comment: you should not answer such type of question at all

Answer (score -1):

After initial authentication, pass the login value using $_SESSION.

Make sure you initiate a session using `session_start();` and destroy the session using `session_destroy();` after your work is done.

Use foreach to display all the comments where necessary.

I recommend reading up basic MySQL and PHP tutorials first.